# Could someone explain what Im doing wrong, in trying to send a text in swift with bluetthooth?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello Im kinda new to Swift. Im trying to send a String from a textfield encoded in utf8 via Bluethooth to another iOS device. Here is the code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Peripheral Side:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{
        
   @IBOutlet weak var textField : UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var switchBtn : UISwitch!
    
    var peripheralManager : CBPeripheralManager?
    var peripheralDevice : CBPeripheral?
    var characteristic : CBMutableCharacteristic?
    
    var data : Data? {
        textField.text?.data(using: .utf8) ?? "Yes".data(using: .utf8)
    }
         
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        peripheralManager?.delegate = self
        peripheralDevice?.delegate = self               
    }
        
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        switch peripheral.state{
        case .poweredOn : setUpPeripheral()
            print("e deschisa conexiunea")
        case .poweredOff: print("conexiunea e inchisa")
        default: print("nu se stie")
        }
    }
    
    private func setUpPeripheral(){
        
        let transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: BTConstants.sampleCharacteristicUUID,
                                                             properties: [.notify,.read],
                                                             value: data ?? nil,
                                                             permissions: [.readable,.writeable])
        
        
        let transferServer = CBMutableService(type: BTConstants.sampleServiceUUID, primary: true)
        
        transferServer.characteristics = [transferCharacteristic]
        peripheralManager?.add(transferServer)
        self.characteristic = transferCharacteristic
    }
    
    
    @IBAction  func swtichButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if switchBtn.isOn{
            peripheralManager!.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [BTConstants.sampleServiceUUID]])
        }
        else{
            peripheralManager?.stopAdvertising()
        }       
        
    }

}
```

The device which is scanning and receiving the String :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,  CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

        
    @IBOutlet weak var textField : UILabel!
           
        var data : Data?
               
        var cbManager : CBCentralManager!
        var peripheralCB : CBPeripheral!         
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
              super.viewDidAppear(animated)
          }
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
         
            cbManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
            
        }
                          
        func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
            switch central.state{
            case .poweredOn  :
                cbManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BTConstants.sampleServiceUUID]
                                              ,options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
            case .poweredOff : self.textField?.text = "poweredOff"
            default : self.textField?.text = "Default"
                
            }
        }        
        
        func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
            self.cbManager?.stopScan()
            
            guard RSSI.intValue >= -50
                    else {
                        os_log("Discovered perhiperal not in expected range, at %d", RSSI.intValue)
                        return
                }
            
            if peripheralCB != peripheral{
                peripheralCB = peripheral
            }
            self.peripheralCB?.delegate = self
            self.data = Data()
            
            
            cbManager?.connect(peripheralCB!, options: nil)

        }
        
        
        func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            if self.peripheralCB == peripheral {
                os_log("Connected to right peripheral")
            }
            peripheralCB?.discoverServices([BTConstants.sampleServiceUUID])
        }
                
        
        func setUp(string : String){
            self.textField?.text = string
        }
            
        
        func peripheral(_ : CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor : CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
            
            if error != nil {
                os_log("this is sparta")
            }
            
            guard let characteristicData = didUpdateValueFor.value,
                   let stringFromData = String(data: characteristicData, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
          
            
            setUp(string: String(data: characteristicData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Doesnt work")
            
           
            }
      
            
        }
```

Comment: What's working, what's not working exactly? Do you succeed in connecting to the second device? Where is the `writeValue(for...)`?

Comment: The textfield that is being written on the peripheral doesn't appear on the other Bluethooth device

Comment: You don't actually create a `CBPeripheralManager` in your "peripheral" view controller. And on your central side you haven't implemented the peripheral delegate methods to discover the service and characteristics and set notification or read the characteristic.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, now I realised.